Creating a bridge firewall with a DSA switch?
I have experimented with converting my BPI R3 router into a switch without success. The switch is a chip built into the router. I seem to be able to bridge two stations plugged in the switch of my BPI R3 router to my upstream router. However, nftables traces display that no frames passes through the bridge hooks. The chains in the bridge family should drop all traffic that pass trough the bridge hooks but without effect. OpenWrt uses the Distributed Switch Architecture technology for my device.
config interface 'loopback'
        option device 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.0.0.1/8'

config device
        option name 'bridge'
        option type 'bridge'
        list ports 'lan1'
        list ports 'lan2'
        list ports 'lan3'

config interface
        option device 'bridge'
        option proto 'none'

root@OpenWrt:/# ip link show master bridge
5: lan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:aa:62:cc:45:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: lan2@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:aa:62:cc:45:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: lan3@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:aa:62:cc:45:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Note: I randomized the MAC address. The three interfaces are UP, but as I've modified the configuration several times, it no longer corresponds to my current configuration, so I've edited the text.
Note:
lan1 is connected to my station STA.
lan2 is connected to my server SRV.
lan3 is connected to my upstream router R1.
I've read that two network interfaces can be used to create a bridge. The DSA documentation states that we can bridge slave interfaces.
Why isn't nftables filtering my packets?

You have a switch, and the purpose of having a switch is that it will perform bridging entirely in hardware – by definition, bypassing the main CPU where nftables logic would live. Adding DSA switch ports to a Linux bridge automatically enables offloading, i.e. configures the switch so that it handles forwarding on its own. The only traffic seen by the CPU is that which is sent to the bridge's MAC address, or to those MAC addresses added via bridge fdb add <...> local (as in docs).
Some switch chips can have hardware-level filtering rules defined, and/or rules for intercepting specific Ethernet packets to the CPU, but – if supported at all – it seems that this can only be configured via tc filter, not via nftables.
